# solr: Using MLT with edismax, is there a way to fetch interesting terms then pass then to edismax regular query?

Tags: solr, clojure

Wanted to enrich morelikethis generated interestingTerms query adding some custom `field:value^boost` to it.

My current solution is:
- run a mlt query seeting `interestingTerms=details`
- building a query from interesting terms (term^score term2^score2...)
- append edismax main query with interesting terms query.

Is there a better solution (maybe even in a single query call?)

EDIT: I also need to use `bf` (boosting functions)

Answer (score 0):

The `/tvrh` handler (the termVector query) does that

You can find my implementation in this [Clojure Solr wrapper](https://github.com/Stylitics/corona) named Corona.

In https://github.com/Stylitics/corona/blob/master/src/corona/query.clj#L187
look at `query-term-vectors` and at `query-mlt-tv-edismax` which uses it.

Another possibility would be to use the `{!mlt ...}` query parser. Docs can be found here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/other-parsers.html#more-like-this-query-parser